# notepad++ regex to replace define sort of data

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to replace texts in huge text file using notepad++. I don't know how can I replace text only if it's length is between for example 50-100. As far as I know in regex it should look like this `[a-zA-Z0-9 -+]{50,100}` but it doesn't work in n++. I'm not a regex specialist.

Example input:

```
<a>short text</a>
<a>veeeeryyyyy lloooooonnngggg teeeexxxtttt</a>
```

Expected output:

```
<a>short text</a>
<a>shrt txt</a>
```

Comment: You forgot to add a space in your character class :)

Comment: It's just a mistake in question. I've already tried it.

Comment: I just tried it and it works, control+h and do not forget check regular expression radio button in dialog box

Comment: And note that your example "veeeeryyyyy lloooooonnngggg teeeexxxtttt" is actually less than 50 chars

Comment: @pepuch I hope you're doing it like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xA1Hi.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or more better is `[^<>]{15,100}` it replace everything between tags

Comment: not possible which version of notepad++ do you have? DId you check regular expression button?

Comment: npp 5.7, regular expression checkbox checked. I'll try it on different version.